# What is the behavior of observeChanges when the internet connection is temporarily lost?

Tags: meteor

Say my client code is observing document additions using the [added callback mechanism](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges).  By design and in perfect conditions, if documents 1,2,3...N are added, client callback should be fired N times.

Now let's say the network connection is lost for periods of time, are there any guarantees/invariants about the number of times that the client added callback will be fired? i.e. can callbacks be logically "lost" due to network issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent question! I was experimenting with this extensively recently as I was writing the [serversync package](https://atmospherejs.com/chfritz/serversync). What I found is this:

If the timeout of the DDP ping is not reached, i.e., the disconnection is only very brief:

Business as usual, no events happen. I believe the default DDP ping timeout from the client is 30 seconds.

Else:

1. As long as you *do not* use the autopublish package on the server, the client will *not* fire its `observeChanges` handlers again upon reconnection. *If* you use autopublish, then `added` events will fire for each document of the collection.
2. You might be interested in knowing that under the hood, DDP *does* send `added` messages to the client upon each reconnection, i.e., on each reconnect DDP sends a full copy of the collection. This happens regardless of whether you use autopublish or not. However, the client seems to be smart enough to know which of these documents he already has, so he doesn't fire the actual `observeChanges` events for documents he already has, only for new, changed, and removed ones. This behavior of DDP may still be relevant to you if you anticipate a lot of disconnections, because it will increase your network traffic considerably -- especially when publishing large collections. I believe this is a ramification of the following note in the [docs of onConnection](http://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-onConnection):

> Currently when a client reconnects to the server (such as after temporarily losing its Internet connection), it will get a new connection each time. The onConnection callbacks will be called again, and the new connection will have a new connection id.
>
> In the future, when client reconnection is fully implemented, reconnecting from the client will reconnect to the same connection on the server: the onConnection callback won’t be called for that connection again, and the connection will still have the same connection id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Helpful indeed!  It sounds like the observeChanges mechanism is designed to tolerate network issues?   i.e. the callbacks get logically queued up until the link is functional.  Are there any Meteor docs that address this?